# Action script - printing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

You can write action scripts to do flash print.
Is there a way to print define the contents in the iframe and print?
Example:
This is a good flash print demo script.

```
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,printContent);

function printContent(evt:MouseEvent) {
    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    if (printJob.start()) {

        if (content_mc.width>printJob.pageWidth) {
            content_mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
            content_mc.scaleY=content_mc.scaleX;
        }

        printJob.addPage(content_mc);
        printJob.send();
    }
}
```

The content_mc is defined within the .fla file. I would like the action script to look at the current web page and print the content within the ifame.
Can this be done? 
Example will be helpful since I’m just learning action scripting.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Directly no.  With a couple of "hacks" yeah.  So to get started you can use ExternalInterface in Flex to communicate with javascript.  That'll be necessary since you can't directly render the IFrame as the browser would within Flex (aside from AIR, even so it's not going to be a 1:1 match in all scenarios).  The second step would be to call window.print() in a javascript function.  Your AS would look something like this:

ExternalInterface.call("doJSPrint");

The last "hack" involved would be to set the media in css to print/screen appropriately on the other elements in the HTML page to just get the IFrame to print.

Relevant links:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

http://www.spikything.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/23/externalinterface_howto/

Good luck, let me know if you think I can provide more info.

Comment: Thank you for the tips but the flash did not printer. Your information did give me some other ideas to try.